# Django - is it possible to iterate over methods?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a Web Application in Django which works with products, prices and statistics etc.

**EDIT:**
More straighforward explanation: How to "group" or "mark" some of instance methods so I can iterate over them like `for method in instance.name_of_the_group`

To keep it simple - I have a model `Product`. `Product` has multiple attributes and methods. Some of those methods returns "statistics" data.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = ...
    ... 

    def save(...
    ...

    def get_all_colors(self):
    ....

    def get_historical_average_price(self): #statistic method
        price = <some calculation>
        return price

    def get_historical_minimal_price(self): #statistic method
        ...
        return price
```

So there is a lot of methods like `get_historical_average_price` and `get_historical_minimal_price`.

Now I have to write labels and call these methods one by one in the project. For example when I generate a table or creating an XML export.

I would like to be able to somehow "mark" them that those are "statistic" methods, give them some name so I would be able to work with them using `for` loops etc.

Is there some way to do that?

Example on XML generator:

```
<products>
    {% for product in products %}
        <product>
            <code>{{ product.code }}</code>
            <name>{{ product.name }}</name>
            <statistics>
                <historical_average>{{ product.get_historical_average_price}}</historical_average>
                <minimal_price>{{ product.get_historical_minimal_price}}</minimal_price>
            </statistics>
        </product>
    {% endfor %}
</products>
```

So I would do something like:

```
<statistics>
{% for statistic_method in product.statistics %}
    <{{ statistic_method.name }}>{{ statistic_method }}</{{ statistic_method.name }}>
{% endfor %}
</statistics>
```

instead of:

```
<statistics>
     <historical_average>{{ product.get_historical_average_price}}</historical_average>
     <minimal_price>{{ product.get_historical_minimal_price}}</minimal_price>
</statistics>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for using custom [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/) as you can use or override the names that they use there.

So in your example, something like :

```
class StatisticsManager(models.Manager):
    def historical_average_price(self):
        ...

class Product(models.Model):
    name = ... 
    statistics = StatisticsManager()
```

Which would then be called in the form

`product_price = Product.statistics.get_historical_average_price`

and so on.

Edit:

I forgot - as you're overriding the default `objects` manager, I believe that you'll need to explicitly restate that as a manager, per [this article](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/higher-level-query-api-django-orm/) - but you can have multiple managers on an object if desired, so `objects`, `statistics`, `otherstuffhere`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how can I use it in the xml generator example I wrote above. Those methods should have something like attributes method.programmatic_name (historical_average_price for xml use) and method.label (Historical AVG price) for uses in Table generating etc.

Comment: Oh wait, maybe I know. I can add attributes to those methods like label = ... etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's it - just the same as you'd use any function, really, but with dot notation!   If it's common enough, I guess you could write the XML fragments into the model manager - they don't need to return querysets. :)

Comment: There is a problem. I'm not able to use Product.objects... anymore... is there a workaround so I can use it the old way?

Comment: I tried it and realized that this is not what I want. Those methods belongs to object not Model. I want to get average price for particular object - product.

Comment: Ah well. (Answered your question about `objects` anyway. :)  Having re-read it, it looks like you're calling those attributes in a template, is that right?