# How to iterate over and filter object methods?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, methods

I'm working on a Django project where I have a model Model.

This model has its attributes, methods and subclasses. I want to iterate over and get methods with "statistics" attribute.

So:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = ...

    def dont_want(self):
        return 'foo'

    def want(self):
        statistic = True
        return self.name

    def want_too(self):
        statistic = True
        return self.name

    def get_methods_with_statistic_attribute(self):
        # WHAT TO DO
        return methods 


model = Model(name='Peter')
for method in model.get_methods_with_statistic_attribute():
    print method

>>> 'Peter'
>>> 'Peter'
```

Is it possible?

I tried:

```
return [a for a in dir(self) if hasattr(getattr(self,a),'statistic')]
```

without success.

**EDIT:**

This problem can be a solution to more specific Django problem I asked here:

[Django - is it possible to iterate over methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063566/django-is-it-possible-to-work-with-model-methods-in-a-for-loop/41063607?noredirect=1#comment69335315_41063607)

Comment: TECHNICALLY you could find methods with a local variable called `statistic` defined in it by doing something like `'statistic' in getattr(self,a).__func__.__code__.co_varnames` but that won't tell you what it is used for inside the function nor is this at all recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because in your example, `statistic` is not an attribute of your method - it's simply a variable which is limited to the method's scope. In other words, your example is **not** equivalent to the following:

```
def want(self):
    # Some code
    return

want.statistics = True
```

which is a *de facto* attribute creation, and in which `getattr()` would actually work.

That said, there's no way to get a list of methods in which there is a variable named `statistics`.

**EDIT**

What you probably want is to define a list of methods which you will call in some specific part of your code. Maybe an option is to define these methods in a constant of your model.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = ...
    USEFUL_METHODS = ['want', 'want_too']

    def dont_want(self):
        return 'foo'

    def want(self):
        statistic = True
        return self.name

    def want_too(self):
        statistic = True
        return self.name

# ...

instance = Model()
for method_str in Model.USEFUL_METHODS:
    method = getattr(instance, method_str)
    method()
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact this was a possible solution to more Django specific problem I've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063566/django-is-it-possible-to-work-with-model-methods-in-a-for-loop/41063607?noredirect=1#comment69335315_41063607

Comment: "there's no way to get a list of methods in which there is a variable named statistics."    [see my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066104/how-to-iterate-over-and-filter-object-methods/41066507#comment69339910_41066104)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inspect the local variables of a function without executing the function and inspecting during it's execution (or looking at it's bytecode) but you can inspect attributes set on the methods themselves.

I would recommend a decorator that adds the `statistic` attribute right after definition to mimic the logic of your current setup

```
def statistics_method(func):
    func.statistic = True
    return func
```

then instead of `statistic = True` inside the function you would put `@statistics_method` right before the definition and the code you currently have would work.